# Postrgresql curl access in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, curl

Im running two simple containers, one with flask app and second app with the postgresql database.
Flask app is able to get/insert data from/to psql. But somehow I can not send a simple curl request to that db:

```
curl localhost:5432
```

or

```
curl <container_name>:5432
```

returns: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

```
curl 0.0.0.0:5432
```

returns `Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 5432: Connection refused`

So this is probably caused by unconfigured psql db. I've tried adding:

```
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
```

to my Dockerfile, but is seems the .conf file is not there, in fact it does not exist in my db at all.
Should I create it manually and if so where?

Comment: "So this is probably caused by unconfigured psql db."  No, when doing `curl 0.0.0.0:5432` to a postgresql installation you will get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.  this seems more like a firewall issue.

Comment: Im getting `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`, when calling `curl localhost:5432` and `curl <container_name>:5432`. Any suggestions @Luuk ?

Comment: You should take more time to ask your question, because "using "localhost", "0.0.0.0" and as a localhost" makes no sense. Why are your trying `localhost` twice ? Where is `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: I've updated the question, hope it is clear now

Comment: No, it's still not clear because you say "But somehow I can not send a simple curl request to that db". And a couple of lines later you gat a response from the server saying "curl: (52) Empty reply from server".  Conclusion, you did send something to the server, and it answered very silently (with an empty response)

Comment: Why are you not trying to connect using a postgresql client ?

Comment: Okay, I wasnt sure if empty reply is good. Unfortunately I have to use curl - that is part of the task. Postgresql client is working ofc

Comment: So, you failed doing the task? Which task is that anyway? you did not mention any task in your question.

Comment: Does asking questions means I've failed?

Comment: It totally depends on the task you where assigned....

Comment: Completely ignoring Docker, `curl` is a tool that makes HTTP requests, but PostgreSQL has a custom non-HTTP wire protocol.  I'm not sure what response you're expecting, but `curl` isn't the right tool.  Do you mean `psql` or another database client tool instead?

Comment: Use `telnet container_name port_number` instead

Answer (score 1):

'Empty reply from server' is the expected result from connecting to PostgreSQL with `curl`.  PostgreSQL is not a web server, it does not speak HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If your Flask app is able to connect to the DB then check what host IP/name you used to connect from Flask to PostgreSQL and put that in your curl command.

By the way, why on earth would you want to use curl in order to connect to your DB? If all that you want is check if the network port is open then use ncat instead.

Comment: got a recruitment taks, thats why